# adb: command not found ( from within the platform-tools directory ) on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: adb, android-sdk-tools

Ultimately I'm trying to get the device id for my note 5.

I've installed Android Studio along with the Platform-Tools 23.1

When I use terminal to go into the platform-tools folder and type adb I get "command not found"

Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since "platform-tools" is probably not part of the system path, you should try running: "./adb" instead of "adb" from the platform-tools location. Or use the full path to it.

Using "." would indicate that you are trying to launch adb from the current directory

Comment: U saved my life :)

Comment: @tatiana_c not just yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok after much search i have come to realize that much of the stackoverflow posts have been marking the wrong and complex answers, for all such questions about adb not working, not found, -bash not found etcccc The only thing that you guys need to do is in terminal just change your directory to platform-tools folder in android SDK
**cd /Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools** 
and then run ./adb --help to see the list since adb is already located inside platform tools no need to export $path and all those vague solutions. Thanks